# Unable to connect AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, authentication, rds

I have created a SQL Server Express instance on RDS. I have also created a security group and enabled SQL Server port range 1433 to everyone. I have also selected Yes for Publicly Accessible.

When I try to connect from the Management Studio, I do specify server name as endpoint of the instance including port number. I did specify the master username and master password with authentication type as SQL Server authentication.

I do get this error when connecting:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)

When I try to see the RDS instance log I see below messages.

```
2016-12-01 22:31:19.65 Logon Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 123.249.0.134]
```

Answer (score 1):

SA is not a possible login, it is disabled in RDS e.g. sysadmin does not exist, nor does the SQL Agent.

Use security groups to control what IP addresses or EC2 instances can connect to your databases on a DB instance. When you first create a DB instance, its firewall prevents any database access except through rules specified by an associated security group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.html